# Oracle Database 18c installation taking forever to install on windows 10

Tags: oracle18c

I'm trying to install Oracle Database 18c locally on my windows 10 pro education but installation is stuck on Creating Oracle XE database even It wasn't allowing to cancel the installation at this point I had to do this through task manager , I have already tried the following as suggested [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4312025/oracle-18c-xe-win10-pro-installation-hangs) but no use:

0)Please disable anti-virus and try again.

1. Is ORACLE_HOME or TNS_ADMIN set in the environment? Go to a command prompt, type "set". You will need to temporarily unset any such environment variables.
2. Are you using Windows 10 Home Edition? It is not supported and the installer is not properly checking for it in the Prerequisite check.
3. Are you using Server 2019? Same issue.
4. On your network adapter that you are using, check (enable) "Client for Microsoft Networks" and "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks".
5. Check to make sure Netbios is enabled on your network connection:
6. In some cases, antivirus has interfered with an installation.  Try installing without AV.
7. Try creating a local user and adding to local administrator group and then log in and install as that user.

[image]

Comment: Have you got a solution on this? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurred because a space was used as a password.